# Django unable to load model into views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, djongo

I am trying to import my models into views.py but I am unable to do so. However I am able to register them on the admin site but when I use the same code I used in admin.py to import the models into views.py, I get an error. I am using djongo so I am not sure if that changes anything about how to import them and I cannot seem to find the documentation for it.

models.py

```py
from djongo import models

class Round(models.Model):
    round_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Round

admin.site.register(Round)
```

views.py

```py
from .models import Round
```

When I try and run my views.py file I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.models'; '**main**' is not a package

Also my views, admin, and models file are all in the same directory. I have made the migrations and I can see my Round model in MongoDB. The only thing I cannot do is import it to the view

Comment: is this a typo from djongo import models check first line in models

Comment: it should be django not djongo

Comment: I am using djongo which is a library that lets me connect to MongoDB instead of creating  a SQL database. I got the first line from the official documentation  of djongo. https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/

Comment: The model is created and I am able to register it on my admin site I just am not able to import it in the views.py file

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file in your directory. It should be inside of your `main` folder and at the same level as your `views.py` and `models.py`

Comment: I do have the __init__.py file in my directory, but it is empty. What should I put in it?

Comment: Hmm... it is supposed to be empty.

Comment: Is there anything else you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, since the models properly migrate to MongoDB. Using pymongo I have just connected to Mongo and have rendered data into my views this way. It works fine so if anybody else has an issue loading in their models, you can always just connect directly to the DB.